# Print content of memory block using GDB

Tags: string, debugging, gdb

Let's say I have const char buff[] = "He\0llo\0 Wo\0rld\0". Hence (gdb)printf "%s", buff will print "He". Is it possible to make GDB show entry buffer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try just `p buff`?

Comment: Yes, the same result as printf.